# C++: cleanup actions in response to Windows logoff

Tags: c++, windows, logoff

I want to catch a Windows logoff event so that I can do some cleanup. My `WindowProc` looks like this:

```
switch (uMsg){
case WM_ENDSESSION:
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
// other messages
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

and the message loop in `WinMain` looks like this:

```
for(;;){
    bool bTerminate = false;
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT){
            bTerminate = true;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if(bTerminate){
        break;
    }
    // do other stuff
    Sleep(10);
}
FILE * fout;
fopen_s(&fout, "C:\\success.txt", "w"); // simulating cleanup actions
fclose(fout);
ExitProcess(0);
```

The intended mechanism is that `WindowProc` does `PostQuitMessage`, causing the main message loop to receive `WM_QUIT`, breaking the loop and sending the program to cleanup. When I exit the program (thus sending `WM_DESTROY`) the program creates `success.txt`, but when the program is running and I log off (sending `WM_ENDSESSION`), it does not.

I have looked at `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` as well, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "Each application should return `TRUE` or `FALSE` immediately upon receiving this message, and defer any cleanup operations until it receives the `WM_ENDSESSION` message."

Answer (score 3):

`WM_ENDSESSION` processing doesn't actually give your application a chance to exit the message loop. You should assume the system calls TerminateProcess after sending the `WM_ENDSESSION` message.

Therefore, any clean-up your application needs to perform should be done before returning from the window procedure.

Comment: In other words, the cleanup code should be called before returning from the window procedure?

Comment: @HarryJohnston That is my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows UI applications, you can use:
    `LRESULT CMainDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

    {
    if(message == WM_ENDSESSION)
    {
    if(lParam == ENDSESSION_LOGOFF)
    {
    /*Handle event*/
    }
    }
    return CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
    }`
You can get more help from [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).